# Make width of element vary according to sibling

Tags: html, css

I want to vary tag-title width based on the tag-subtitle's width.Currently i have given max-width of tag-title as 70% and added text-ellipses class to it. But if tag-subtitle content width increases it goes to a new line which i want to prevent. I only want tag-title width to vary and add ellipses to text on overflow and tag-subtitle's width to expand according to content width.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.tag {
  position: relative;
  width: 291px;
  height: 36px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 11px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: 0.15px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 16px;
  background: rgb(226, 244, 248);
}

.tag-info {
  width: 125px;
  height: 16px;
}

.tag-title {
  max-width: 70%;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.tag-subtitle {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.pull-left {
  float: left !important;
}

.pull-right {
  float: right !important;
}

.text-ellipsis {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="tag">
  <div class="tag-info pull-left">
    <span class="tag-title pull-left text-ellipsis">abcdefghijklmnop</span>
    <span class="tag-subtitle pull-left" style="color: rgb(73, 169, 90);">(KII1)</span>
  </div>
  <span class="pull-right tag-range">9:00 AM - 10:00 AM</span>
</div>
```

> I need it to work on IE10 as well.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you need that middle element should take all place, if it is correct, than it can be achieved `display: flex`:

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 291px;  
  padding: 10px 11px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: 0.15px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 16px;
  background: rgb(226, 244, 248);
}

.child1 {
  flex-basis: 125px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.child2 {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: violet;
}

.one {
  flex-basis: 30%;
  padding-right: 1px;
}

.two {
  flex: 1;
}


.text-ellipsis {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.tag-info {
  width: 125px;
  height: 16px;
}
```

```html
  <div class="parent" style="background-color: pink;">
    <div class="child1 tag-info">
        <div class="one text-ellipsis" >
          abcdefghijklmnop
        </div>
        <div class="two child2" >
          (KI1)123
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="child2">
      9:00 AM - 10:00 AM
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: no..the first and 2nd element are part of tag-info which has a fixed width...i want the second element to expand to fit it's content and first element's width to vary according to that

Answer (score 1):

Hiii, Check this solution

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <style type="text/css">
            * {
                box-sizing: border-box;
            }

            .tag {
                position: relative;
                width: 291px;
                height: 36px;
                display: inline-flex;
                padding: 10px 11px;
                border-radius: 4px;
                font-weight: 400;
                letter-spacing: 0.15px;
                font-size: 14px;
                line-height: 16px;
                background: rgb(226, 244, 248);
                align-items: center;
                justify-content: space-between;
            }

            .tag-info {
                max-width: 125px;
                height: 16px;
                display: flex;
                align-items: center;
            }

            .tag-title {
                max-width: 70%;
                text-transform: capitalize;
                margin-right: 5px;
            }

            .tag-subtitle {
                text-transform: uppercase;
            }

            .text-ellipsis {
                overflow: hidden;
                text-overflow: ellipsis;
                white-space: nowrap;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="tag">
            <div class="tag-info pull-left">
            <span class="tag-title pull-left text-ellipsis">abcdefghijklmnop</span>
            <span class="tag-subtitle pull-left" style="color: rgb(73, 169, 90);">(KII1)</span>
            </div>
            <span class="pull-right tag-range">9:00 AM - 10:00 AM</span>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```